# Select option value change effect in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, list, user, territory

I have a specific case where a particular ID value is in constructor. Hence, it runs only during the page loads. Now on VF page a select option field value change makes the ID value to change. But the change is not effecting at List userterrLst values.

**Constructor Code**

```
  public cntl_AbvProductAllocation_dummy()
        { ........
     excludedNodes = new Set<String>();
            Set<string> paSFList = new Set<String>();
            Allocation_Settings_abv__c allocSetting = [Select Criteria_abv__c from Allocation_Settings_abv__c where Feature_abv__c = 'Product Allocation' and RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Feature_Candidates' limit 1];
            String userTerrQuery = 'Select userId,TerritoryId from UserTerritory where userId in (Select Id from User where IsActive = True';
            if(allocSetting != null && allocSetting.Criteria_abv__c != null)
                paSFList.addAll(allocSetting.Criteria_abv__c.split(';;'));        
            paSFList.remove(null);  

            //Sample Order Campaign

            Set<string> paSOCList = new Set<String>();
            Sample_Order_Campaign_abv__c soc= [Select Franchises_abv__c from Sample_Order_Campaign_abv__c where Id=:selcampaign and active_abv__c=true limit 1];
           // String userTerrQuery = 'Select userId,TerritoryId from UserTerritory where userId in (Select Id from User where IsActive = True';
            if(soc!= null && soc.Franchises_abv__c != null)
                paSOCList.addAll(soc.Franchises_abv__c.split(';;'));        
            paSOCList.remove(null);    
            //Prep User Terr Map         
            List<UserTerritory> userTerrLst = [Select userId,TerritoryId from UserTerritory where userId in (Select Id from User where IsActive = True and (Salesforce_abt__c in :paSOCList) and (Salesforce_abt__c in :paSFList or Profile.Name in ('System Administrator','Abbott Sample Administration')))] ;
.......

}
```

**Apex Page**

Below is the Page code where Select List value changes.

```
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">
                                    Campaign
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body"><center>
                                <apex:selectList value="{!selCampaign}" size="1">
                              <apex:selectOptions value="{!campaigns}"></apex:selectOptions>
                              <apex:actionSupport action="{!updProductList}" event="onchange" status="actStatusId"  reRender="pivot,hierPb,pb"/>
                              </apex:selectList> </center>
                            </div>                        
                        </div>
```

**updProductList method**

During change of selectlist below method fires.

```
 public void updProductList()
    {    
        excludedNodes = new Set<String>();
        Set<string> paSFList = new Set<String>();
        Allocation_Settings_abv__c allocSetting = [Select Criteria_abv__c from Allocation_Settings_abv__c where Feature_abv__c = 'Product Allocation' and RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Feature_Candidates' limit 1];
        String userTerrQuery = 'Select userId,TerritoryId from UserTerritory where userId in (Select Id from User where IsActive = True';
        if(allocSetting != null && allocSetting.Criteria_abv__c != null)
            paSFList.addAll(allocSetting.Criteria_abv__c.split(';;'));        
        paSFList.remove(null);  

        //Sample Order Campaign

        Set<string> paSOCList = new Set<String>();
        Sample_Order_Campaign_abv__c soc= [Select Franchises_abv__c from Sample_Order_Campaign_abv__c where Id=:selcampaign and active_abv__c=true limit 1];
       // String userTerrQuery = 'Select userId,TerritoryId from UserTerritory where userId in (Select Id from User where IsActive = True';
        if(soc!= null && soc.Franchises_abv__c != null)
            paSOCList.addAll(soc.Franchises_abv__c.split(';;'));        
        paSOCList.remove(null);    
        //Prep User Terr Map         
        List<UserTerritory> userTerrLst = [Select userId,TerritoryId from UserTerritory where userId in (Select Id from User where IsActive = True and (Salesforce_abt__c in :paSOCList) and (Salesforce_abt__c in :paSFList or Profile.Name in ('System Administrator','Abbott Sample Administration')))] ;

        selectedProductlot=null;
        productList = new List<SelectOption>();

        if(userType == 'Rep'){
            for(Product_vod__c prod :[SELECT  Id, Name, Active_abv__c from Product_vod__c where Product_type_vod__c ='BRC' and Active_abv__c = 'Yes' and Parent_Product_vod__c in (select Product_vod__c from My_Setup_Products_vod__c where OwnerId = :curUser.id) and 
                                        Id in (Select Catalog_Product_abv__c from Sample_Order_Campaign_Product_abv__c where Sample_Order_Campaign_abv__c = :selCampaign)])
            {
                productList.add(new SelectOption(prod.id,prod.Name)); 
                if(selectedProductlot == null)
                    selectedProductlot = prod.id;
            }

        }else{
            //for(Product_vod__c prod :[SELECT  Id, Name, Active_abv__c from Product_vod__c where Product_type_vod__c ='BRC' and Active_abv__c = 'Yes' and Id in (Select Product_abv__c from Sample_Form_Allocations_abv__c where active_abv__c = true)
                                   // and Id in (Select Catalog_Product_abv__c from Sample_Order_Campaign_Product_abv__c where Sample_Order_Campaign_abv__c = :selCampaign)])
            for(Product_vod__c prod :[SELECT  Id, Name, Active_abv__c from Product_vod__c where Product_type_vod__c ='BRC' and Active_abv__c = 'Yes' and 
                                        Id in (Select Catalog_Product_abv__c from Sample_Order_Campaign_Product_abv__c where Sample_Order_Campaign_abv__c = :selCampaign)])
            {
                productList.add(new SelectOption(prod.id,prod.Name)); 
                if(selectedProductlot == null)
                    selectedProductlot = prod.id;
            }
        }
        /*
        for(Product_vod__c prod :[SELECT  Id, Name, Active_abv__c from Product_vod__c where Product_type_vod__c ='BRC' and Active_abv__c = 'Yes' and Id in (select Product_vod__c from Sample_lot_vod__c where Active_vod__c = true)
                                    and Id in (Select Catalog_Product_abv__c from Sample_Order_Campaign_Product_abv__c where Sample_Order_Campaign_abv__c = :selCampaign)])
        {
            productList.add(new SelectOption(prod.id,prod.Name )); 
            if(selectedProductlot == null)
                selectedProductlot = prod.id;
        }
        */
        refreshAvailableQuantities();               

    }
```

Comment: just write this query in some method and call that method from constructor. Now next time when user change parameter then again call this query method. Are you facing any challenge here?

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Usually by opening an IDE. Apologies for the snark, but I'm having a hard time believing that you've written the code that you've provided while not knowing how to make/use a helper method.

Comment: I have not written the code, but I have to modify it surely. Me too having tough time here @DerekF  :(